# Run process in background as SU from Dockerfile

Tags: python, linux, docker

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN useradd -m client && echo "client:client" | chpasswd 

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN mkdir /execute
RUN mkdir /super
WORKDIR /super

COPY /run /super

RUN python supervisor.py & sleep 1

WORKDIR /execute

RUN chown -R client /execute/

USER client
```

supervisor.py is:

```
def run_supervisor():
    while True:
        filename = "/execute/" + "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for j in range(8)]) + ".txt"

        helper.execute(f"echo floose > {filename}")

        time.sleep(10)

#

run_supervisor()
```

Finally, I run the container with:

```
docker run --network host -it --entrypoint '/bin/bash' --privileged client_image:latest -c "bash /super/start_client.sh && /bin/bash"
```

My intention is for supervisor.py to continue running as root, while the user is logged in as user "client".

supervisor.py does run, as there is one randomly titled .txt file in /execute when the container starts.  However at some point during the start process it appears that the process is terminated.

How can I have supervisor.py continue running as root?

Comment: Typical practice would be to only run one process per container; the two containers can have different users and different primary commands.  If you're running privileged containers with host networking, it also may be more straightforward to just run the processes directly on the host (you're disabling some of the key isolation features).

Comment: Thank you.  In this specific case I would really like to have the super user process running in the background... is there a way I can achieve it?